Rotating a Barcode in TCPDF when embedded in HTML
Im generating a PDF in PHP with a barcode.  Within the document, I need one vertical barcode and one horizontal.
Heres my sample code.  The barcodes generate fine.
$data = $pdf->serializeTCPDFtag('write1DBarcode', array($consignment_ID, 'C128', '', '', 165, 20, 0.4, array('position' => 'S', 'border' => false, 'padding' => 4, 'fgcolor' => array(0, 0, 0), 'bgcolor' => array(255, 255, 255), 'text' => false, 'font' => 'helvetica', 'fontsize' => 8, 'stretchtext' => 4), 'N'));

    $data2 = $pdf->serializeTCPDFtag('write1DBarcode', array($consignment_ID, 'C128', '', '', 174, 20, 0.4, array('position' => 'S', 'border' => false, 'padding' => 4, 'fgcolor' => array(0, 0, 0), 'bgcolor' => array(255, 255, 255), 'text' => false, 'font' => 'helvetica', 'fontsize' => 8, 'stretchtext' => 4), 'N'));


    $html = '<tcpdf data="' . $data . '" />';
       $html .= '<tcpdf data="' . $data2 . '" />';


    // output the HTML content
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -



    //Close and output PDF document
    $pdf->Output('Label.pdf', 'I');

Ive tried using CSS but TCPDF doesnt not allow rotation using CSS. Is there a way to rotate the $data2 serialized tag?
Ive looked at https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_013/ but cannot see a way to apply these transformations to a serialized tag.
Heres what i have also tried;
$data = $pdf->serializeTCPDFtag('write1DBarcode', array($consignment_ID, 'C128', '', '', 165, 20, 0.4, array('position' => 'S', 'border' => false, 'padding' => 4, 'fgcolor' => array(0, 0, 0), 'bgcolor' => array(255, 255, 255), 'text' => false, 'font' => 'helvetica', 'fontsize' => 8, 'stretchtext' => 4), 'N'));

    

    $html = '
    
    <table>
    

    <tr>
        <td colspan="14" style="text-align:center;margin-top:10px;font-size:5px">&nbsp;<BR><tcpdf data="' . $data . '" /></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="7">';

    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);

    $pdf->StartTransform();
    $pdf->Rotate(-90);
    $data2 = $pdf->serializeTCPDFtag('write1DBarcode', array($consignment_ID, 'C128', '', '', 174, 20, 0.4, array('position' => 'S', 'border' => false, 'padding' => 4, 'fgcolor' => array(0, 0, 0), 'bgcolor' => array(255, 255, 255), 'text' => false, 'font' => 'helvetica', 'fontsize' => 8, 'stretchtext' => 4), 'N'));
    $html = '<tcpdf data="' . $data2 . '" />';
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);
    $pdf->StopTransform();

    $html = '</td>
       
    </tr>

....
OTHER COLUMNS HERE
....


</table>';


    // output the HTML content
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -



    //Close and output PDF document
    $pdf->Output('Label.pdf', 'I');



Call StartTransform(), Rotate(), WriteHTML() and StopTransform() for the vertical barcode, then WriteHTML() for the horizontal one.

The above is a shorterned version of my code.  The two barcodes are shown in two different areas of a page.  I usually only call writeHTML() once.  Can i call this twice when rendering one page? I tried this but that didnt seem to work;  $pdf->StartTransform();  $pdf->Rotate(-90);  $html .= '<tcpdf data="' . $data2 . '" />';  $pdf->StopTransform();

You must call WriteHTML() before StopTransform(). And yes, you can call WriteHTML() several times.

You can also call write1DBarcode() directly (see here).

Thanks so much for the replies! My HTML has a Table, and the two barcodes are in different Columns. If I call writeHTML() before my tags are closed, TCPDF just returns a blank page. I will update the post to show what i tried.

If you have a single row and the columns have a fixed width: you can put the table without the barcodes, then add them with write1DBarcode().
